# Which messages are included in (D)TLS Finished message's verify_data field for session resumption

Tags: tls, handshake

The https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.9 states which messages are included for PRF computation that is included in `Finished` messages

It is clear for 'regular' (initial) handshake

But assume that the client wants to resume the DTLS session

Client sends the `ClientHello` with previous `SessionID` field
The server responds with `ServerHello`, sends `ChangeCipherSpec` (not included for `verify_data` computation) and `Finished`

Which messages should be included for `verify_data` field computation in `Finished` message sent from server?
A. Should it be only the most recent (resuming) `ClientHello` and `ServerHello`
B. Should it be the most recent (resuming) `ClientHello` and `ServerHello` **plus** previous (initial in our example) handshake messages?